# Solving recurrence with boundary conditions on both sides

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, recursion

I want to solve the following recurrence, for any parameter $x>0$:

$ a[i]= \frac{1}{x} a[i+1]+ (1- \frac{1}{x}) a[i-1]$ for $i \in \{1,...,n-1\}$

$a[0]= 0, a[n]=1$.

i.e. find a closed form for $a[i]$ for any $i \in \{0,...,n\}$

I know that the solution must be
$\frac{(x-1)^i-1}{(x-1)^n-1}$,

but I want to find this solution myself. My approach was using the generating function as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409805/find-a-closed-formula-for-a-recursive-function-using-generating-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1), however, I am not sure how to deal with the boundary conditions giving ``on both sides'' i.e. a[0] and a[n].

How can I find the closed solution (using the generating function technique)?

Comment: Hint: the recurrence in standard form is $\,a_{k+1}=xa_k-(x-1)a_{k-1}\,$, with characteristic polynomial $\,t^2-xt+x-1 = (t-1)\left(t-(x-1)\right)\,$, so $\,a_k = \lambda \cdot 1^k + \mu \cdot (x-1)^k\,$. Use the two conditions for $\,k=0\,$ and $\,k=n\,$ to determine $\,\lambda, \mu\,$.