# Finding associated Difference equation.

Tags: recurrence-relations

Assume I have some arbitrary difference equation, which should equate to $2^{n+3} - 1$. A quick way to solve this is to use the annihilator method, but I have not fully understanded how to use this. My main problem lies within finding the difference equation where the before mentioned $2^{n+3} -1 $ would be the solution. I know from the solutions that $y(n+2) -3y(n+1) + 2y(n)$ is the difference equation solved by $2^{n+3} -1 $, but how do I (quickly) find this?

Comment: The recurrence relation you posted earlier is different from this one??  Also, have you tested it to make sure it is solved by $2^{n+3}-1$?

Comment: I maybe stated my question wrong, I know this is not the same difference equation as in my previous question, I am merely interested in a way to find a difference equation from a solution. If you find the difference equation of the RHS and (as given in my previous question) the LHS, you can use both characteristic equation to find the general solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Consider a generalized Fibonacci sequence

$$
f_n=af_{n-1}+bf_{n-2}
$$

As I've pointed out previously [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152925/decimal-fibonacci-number/2198774#2198774), for example, the characteristic roots are given by

$$
\alpha, \beta = \frac{a \pm\sqrt{a^2 + 4b}}{2}.
$$

Since you provide $\alpha=2, \beta=1$ we can determine that $a=3$ from $\alpha+\beta=3$ and $b=-2$ from $\alpha-\beta=1$, i.e., $\sqrt{a^2+4b}=1$ or $b=(1-a^2)/4$.

To complete the solution, we need the general solution to the recurrence above. It can be expressed follows,

$$
f_n=\frac{(f_1-f_0\beta)\alpha^n - (f_1-f_0\alpha)\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}
$$

With the information you provide, $f_0=2^3-1=7, f_1=2^4-1=15$ and we can the readily show that, indeed

$$
f_n=2^{n+3}-1
$$

for

$$
f_n=3f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2},\quad f_0=7,f_1=15
$$

Answer (score 0):

Noting that the sequence also satisfies the first-order inhomogeneous difference equation $f_{n+1} = 2 f_n + 1$, if we want to find a homogeneous equation then we can start by writing

$$f_{n+2} = a f_{n+1} + b f_n$$

and then do some substitutions and expansions. That will give us:

$$\begin{eqnarray}& 2^{n + 5} - 1 & = & a\left(2^{n + 4} - 1\right) + b\left(2^{n + 3} - 1\right) \\
& 32 \cdot 2^n - 1 & = & a\left(16 \cdot 2^n - 1\right) + b\left(8 \cdot 2^n - 1\right) \\
& & = & \left(16 a + 8 b\right) 2^n - \left(a + b\right) \\
\implies & 16 a + 8 b & = & 32 \\
\mbox{and} & a + b & = & 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

and you can solve the last two equations quite easily to get $a = 3, b = -2$.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer! How do you recognize to start with $f_{n+2} = af_{n+1} + bf_n$? For the rest it is all very helpful!

Comment: One way to recognise it is by seeing that there are two components to the term - a constant $-1$ and a $2^n$-based part. So if we want to create a difference equation we probably need it to have two coefficients (so that we can create two equations in two unknowns).

Comment: But when we have $3^n$ on the RHS, we recognise it has only one term $3^n$ but this is the solution to $(f_{n+1} - 3f_n)$. How can there be a recognizeable pattern?

Comment: Say for example we have on the RHS the term $n^2$, what would your 'guess' of the number of coefficients be?