# Why is a=43 an exception?

Tags: golden-ratio, alternating-expression

There is a sequence. The first integer is positive, the second integer is negative. An alternating part is a part that switches between positive and negative (0 is not included)

(a) I have a complete answer to this part

(b) What second term should be chosen to get the longest possible switching between positive and negative

For b, I wrote an entire proof as to why, assuming a is the positive first integer, b is the integer closest to -0.618a. However, I was testing cases today, and I found that a=43 is an exception to this. 0.618 multiplied by a would be -26.57 something, which is about -27. However, the number to make the sequence the longest is actually -26.

Could anyone give me a hint as to why this happened?

Comment: What does this proof look like? Where does the reasoning break down for $a = 43$?

Comment: This is linear recurrence. It is possible to use Binet idea to find explicit formula

Comment: I'm not sure if it's really a proof, but basically, since the sequence in this problem is pretty much the Fibonacci sequence, I found the closed form for the Fibonacci sequence. Then, I solved for the coefficients assuming that the first term is a and the second term is b and found their relationship

Comment: I'd suggest writing out at least the broad structure of your "proof". For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How do you want to deal with the case that the value zero occurs? For example $8 ,-4 ,4, 0$. Does the zeo count as "alternating"?

Comment: I believe that 0 does not count as alternating because it is neither positive nor negative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have posed an interesting question here, but have not shown how you got to where you are. If you look at a [previous link of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037895/modified-binets-formula-for-fibonacci-sequence/2235956#2235956), you'll find a general solution to the problem $f_n=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$ with arbitrary initial conditions, say $f_0$ and $f_1$, or $a$ and $b$ in your notation. It easy to show that your solution can be expressed as

$$
f_n=\bigg(b-\frac{a}{2}\bigg)F_n+\frac{a}{2}L_n
$$

where $F_n$ and $L_n$ are the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers, respectively. Here you can see that the Fibonacci terms are always negative while the Lucas terms are all positive (for $a>0$ and $b<0$).

This can also be expressed as

$$
f_n=bF_n+aF_{n-1}
$$

Now, we can express the Fibonacci number with the Binet formula as follows

$$
F_n=\frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}
$$

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio and $\psi=1-\varphi$. Thus

$$
f_n=\frac{b(\varphi^n-\psi^n)+a(\varphi^{n-1}-\psi^{n-1})}{\varphi-\psi}
$$

Almost there. For large $n$ we have $\varphi^n>>\psi^n$ and the above becomes

$$
f_n\approx\frac{\varphi^{n-1}}{\varphi-\psi}(b\varphi+a)
$$

From this we can see that if $\ b\varphi+a=0$, $\ f_n\to 0$ for large $n$. In fact, I tried this numerically, and it seems to oscillate forever. Now, if $\ b\varphi+a<0$, then the negative terms dominate and the series goes negative. Likewise, if $\ b\varphi+a>0$, then the series goes positive.

To sum up, the point is the criterion you found, i.e., $\ b\varphi+a=0$ for determining the value of $b$ that gives the longest oscillation, is only approximate. However, if you allow non-integer values of $b=-a/\varphi$, then you can oscillate forever.

Comment: Hi! I believe I came to this conclusion, but my question is, after some testing and observation, I was wondering why a=43 does not follow this. Theoretically, b should be -27 to make this oscillate the longest, however it is actually -26

Comment: @confused Remember, that theoretical result is just an approximation for large values of $n$, and $n$ is not large here. I plotted up the results for $b=[-26,-27]$ and found that $b=-26$ just barely crosses the $x$-axis once more than for $b=-27$ at $n=5$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to verify that the smallest values for $A$ and $B$ that yield a certain number of alternating values, are found when the series ends with $(1, -1)$. Working backwards the optimal pairs $(A, B)$ are given by: $(1, -1)$, $(2,-1)$, $(3, -2)$, $(5, -3)$, $(8, -5)$, $(13,-8)$, $(21, -13)$, $(34, -21)$, $(55,-34)$, $(89,-55)$. One will notice that these are the Fibonacci numbers.

If you start with some other value for $A$, the number of oscillations is always smaller. This is in particular true when $B$ differs by roughly $0.5$ from the optimal value. The rounding up or down is not always logical. I found eight cases for $A \le 100$ where $B$ had to be rounded differently than one would expect. Here they are:

$(4, -3)$ where the value $2.472$ was rounded up

$(9, -5)$ where the value $5.562$ was rounded down

$(25, -16)$ where the value $15.451$ was rounded up

$(43, -26)$ where the value $26.575$ was rounded down

$(48, -29)$ where the value $29.666$ was rounded down

$(51, -31)$ where the value $31.520$ was rounded down

$(64, -39)$ where the value $39.554$ was rounded down

$(93, -58)$ where the value $57.477$ was rounded up